# Page refresh in Angular2 navigates to Home page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am working on a Angular 2 Project and facing an issue with routing. Let's say I am currently at the URL http://localhost:58736/#/page1 now when I am refreshing the page by pressing F5, it redirects me to the Home Page.
Following is my route config file --

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: "dashboard", component: DashboardComponent },
{ path: "home", component: HomePageComponent, pathMatch: "full" },
{ path: "page1", component: Page1Component },
{ path: "page2", component: Page2Component },
{ path: "404", component: Error404Component },
{ path: "", redirectTo: "/home", pathMatch: "full" }];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't use HashLocationStrategy, you shouldn't expect the router recognize the route with hash.